# C++ Object array stack overflow

Tags: c++

when i try to create an array of 'gameObject'-s i get a stack overflow exception, any idea what might be the reason?
Edit: for an array of 1 it DOES NOT throw an exception, i was mistaken
(creating just a 'gameObject' variable is fine)

I know my code is messy, and just all around bad, but i'm fairly new to c++ so please excuse my code :(

Here is my Main.cpp:

```
int main()
{
using namespace std::literals::chrono_literals;

HWND myconsole = GetConsoleWindow();
HDC mydc = GetDC(myconsole);

bool loop;
loop = false;

std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point start;
std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point end;
std::chrono::duration<float> duration;

gameObject test(mydc, "test.dat");
gameObject objList[100];

test.posX = 200;
test.posY = 10;

std::cout << getCurrentId();

while (true)
{
    start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();



    if (GetKeyState(VK_DOWN) & 0x8000)
    {
        test.move(0, -3);       
    }

    if (GetKeyState(VK_UP) & 0x8000)
    {
        test.move(0, 3);
    }

    if (GetKeyState(VK_RIGHT) & 0x8000)
    {
        test.move(6, 0);
    }

    if (GetKeyState(VK_SPACE) & 0x8000)
    {
        gameObject shell(mydc, "shell.dat");
        shell.type = 1;
        shell.posX = test.posX + test.l;
        shell.posY = test.posY + test.h;
        objList[getCurrentId()] = shell;
    }

    if (loop == false)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            if (objList[i].type == 1)
            {
                objList[i].move(1, 0);
            }
        }
    }

    if (loop == false)
    {
        loop = true;
    }
    else
    {
        loop = false;
    }

    end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    duration = end - start;

    if (duration < 0.0333s)
    {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(0.0333s - duration);
    }


}
}
```

and here is the 'gameObject' class:

```
class gameObject
{
public:
    gameObject(HDC currentDc, std::string dataFile);
    gameObject();
    ~gameObject();

    void clear();
    void draw();

    void move(int x, int y);

    void loadSprite(std::string spriteName);

    bool collide(gameObject);

    unsigned short h = 1;
    unsigned short l = 1;

    int posX;
    int posY;

    unsigned short type;

    COLORREF spriteData[256][256];

    unsigned short id;




    HDC dc;
};
```

Comment: " `if (loop == false)
    {
        loop = true;
    }
    else
    {
        loop = false;
    }` " --> `loop = !loop;`

Comment: well :D that makes sense, like i said im kinda new

Comment: What is `COLORREF` (how large is it?) What's your stack size?

Comment: COLORREF is a windows type for an rgb definition (i assume 3 bytes)

Comment: COLORREF is 4 bytes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating all your objects on the stack `gameObject objList[100];`, and each of them has a big array in them `COLORREF spriteData[256][256];`. That's your stack overflow.

Use a `std::vector` to store your objects.

Comment: hm, but i expect to have quite a few objects at one time, should i store them on the heap instead?
also, if i make the array smaller (1 member) then i get an access violation error
at this line:
`if (objList[i].type == 1)`

Comment: Or if it always stays the initial length, maybe use `std::make_unique<gameObject[]>(100)`.

Comment: Yes, the stack is small, you shouldn't store big objects there. If you have an access violation, debug the code to see where you are going out of bounds and why.

Comment: @Kivi `std::vector` will take care of that for you. Just use `std::vector`.

Comment: does `std::vector` take care of memory management? i mean if i am going up to 100 objects, it will still take up all that memory

Comment: Yes, but on the heap. Please look at the documentation. Glad you sorted it out!